# Which files need to be placed in a src directory when installing flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, flowtype, yarnpkg

I am attempting to install flow and am following along with the official documentation found [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/).

However I am stuck at the step that asks users to do the following:

> If you then put all your source files in a src directory you can compile them to another directory by running:

```
yarn run babel src/ -- -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/
```

I am not sure which files are the 'source files'. Does this mean all of the files in my project root or only specific files? When I moved all of the files into a src folder I received this error:

> -d doesn't exist. lib/ doesn't exist

Which files are the 'source files' that need to be moved into a src folder?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, source files will refer to the files that you write (as opposed to the files automatically created when you use react-native init) and they are usually in a file called 'src'.  Hope that helps.